# Using Java/Selenium to read data from Google spreadsheet document

Tags: java, selenium, google-docs

I have a simple Google spreadsheet doc (a list of site URLs) that gets created by a script:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aPpgCIWG0ASw1GgRQneVzJu8mHlLXWrk60_4WGELbaI

I want to navigate a Firefox browser to each URL and run my link checker against each URL. Is there a way to do this without authorizing tokens and such? I'm not having much luck finding good, current info on this. I am using Eclipse and Java 1.8 and I build with a POM.xml file and Maven.

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Comment: Two things that aren't immediately clear to me are why you need to use selenium and why you are storing your links on Google Docs. But if you MUST access a document on google docs. Use the Sheets API. https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java

Comment: I found that page to be way too much since I'm just doing a read-only to what is there. (And why Gradle??) Selenium is not technically part of this, but I included it for QA folks like me trying to find answers. The Google doc is created by another group upstream of me. It's my starting point that I have no control over.

Comment: Then the sheet's api is how you access the file from java. You don't have to use Gradle,  you just include those same dependencies in Maven and you should be good to go. The example code does literally exactly what you are asking for and will do it with only slight modification.

Comment: That leaves me exactly in the same place - stuck. I was hoping someone who has done this would share a code snippet for me to get a handle on it. If I knew how to do this I wouldn't be asking for help.